# How to automate cefsharp browser that is embedded to a wpf application using selenium C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, ui-automation, cefsharp

I have a wpf application which is embedded to a cefsharp browser, I need to enter my login credentials in cefbrowser first for accessing the wpf application?

Can someone please help me with this as I'm very new to C# and would be very helpful if you can explain the code.

Comment: What do you need selenium for? You question is rather lacking in detail. Executing JavaScript directly will be much easier than trying to attach selenium. Start with https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#1-how-do-you-call-a-javascript-method-from-net

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @amaitland My objective is to automate the automate the wpf desktop application, But I need to enter my login info in the attached cefsharp browser in order to access the wpf application. I'm able to locate elements and verify the wpf application, But struck with this cefsharp browser. not sure how to access it or control through selenium

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/UsingChromeDriver.md should give you some pointers, you can enable remote debugging using the --remote-debugging-port=XXXX command line argument.

Comment: Personally I'd be using puppeteer Sharp over selenium, see https://gist.github.com/amaitland/52831ce341f65554540d91eba951bebe for a slightly outdated example of connecting puppeteer Sharp to an already running browser.